# Is there a way to legally refuse to pay the public broadcasting payment in Germany

Tags: germany, payment

Recently I've got a 385 Euro bill for Rundfunkbeiträge - it's a payment every German household should pay for public broadcasting. I was frustrated, however my coworkers told me that this is for almost two years and, well, I have no other option rather than just to put up with it, which I did. Now I've got bill 52 Euro for next three months and I've found that's is psychologically difficult for me to pay for something **apart from taxes** from  that I don't even use.

My question would be - talking into account that this is not a tax - is there any legal way not to pay for public broadcasting.

Comment: Other than a death certificate, nothing will work.

Comment: @gnasher729 sooner or later I think I end up with this ))))

Comment: The legal way is not having your own household. Join a shared flat and complain about it as a group (as the main tenant still has to pay and would certainly bill the others.)